# Mongoid: model which belongs_to some model doesn't update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I got these two model:

```
class A
 include Mongoid::Document

 has_many :child, :class_name => "B", :inverse_of => :parent

 field :name
end

class B
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "A", :inverse_of => :child

  field :name
end

p = A.new
p.name = "father"
c = B.new
c.name = "son"
c.save
p.child << c
p.save
c.save
```

When i create a child and set the parent, everything is just fine. If i create a child  without specifying the parent and saving it, that works as well. But i can't uppdate the parent_id after saving child. I have tested these proccess in rails console and got no error.

Appreciate any idea that approach the solution.

Comment: By convention, Rails requires a plural name for has_many, and child is singular.  Even though you can override with class_name and/or irregular inflections, I'd recommend reworking your problem to follow Rails conventions and to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Try gem [mongoid-ancestry](https://github.com/skyeagle/mongoid-ancestry) for trees structure in db.
If you use it, changes will be minimal, but it's work

Comment: isn't it for active record?

Comment: oops! sorry, fixed on mongoid-ancestry

Comment: Thanks for that, i have not tried it yet though. But why it doesn't work properly?

Comment: Can you write what are you doing in console? Update complete, if parent_id exist?

Answer (score 1):

When you use ***new*** it's create instance, but not save in db. And when you set child for parent, mongoid validate relation via a validates_associated but it's not in db.
Try use ***create*** instead ***new*** or

```
p.save
```

before set relation.